# Why Google Play Music app gets turned off when I'm running?

Tags: google-play-music

Whenever I go for a run and I'm using my [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music&hl=en) app, my phone turns off within 5-10 minutes, causing said app to turn off.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

<sup>If relevant I have a [Samsung Galaxy S III](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxys3/).</sup>

Comment: Perhaps screen times out after 5-10 minutes... is there a setting in Google Music app to keep alive after screen goes off?

Comment: No settings that I can find either on the app or on the device to control this behavior... For me it keeps on playing the music with locked screen, after screen timeout, using other apps, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings within Google Play Music for 'Stream via WiFi Only'. If you have this set, and you're out of range, the streaming cannot continue until you return within range. It may just be coincidental to always appear consistently at that time or range.
Also remember about caching. Caching may queue a number of songs, making it appear to extend range.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a overheating problem especially if you are using live wallpapers AND leave the radios (WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS and Mobile data) on.  Is your device in some time of case?  That might prevent cooling...I have run into this problem occasionally and have learned to turn off things.